# How is the api doc generated @ http://api.highcharts.com/

Tags: gwt, highcharts, google-closure, autobean

I cannot find anything relate to it from github https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com

Guessing

1. Google Closure Library javadoc parser
   https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#tags
2. Custom Code?

I wanted to generate Java POJO interfaces to be used with GWT AutoBean and JSON processing. Currently I am stuck **handcoding** the interfaces to be same as the properties mentioned in the api site. This is not maintainable solution as i would need to update it for every release of highcharts and highstocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [Highcharts API page](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) you'll find two download links in the menu on the left. One for download all options as JSON and one for XML format. This can be used for generating your interfaces.

Comment: Thanks. It improves my approach and gives scope for auto-generation pojos. I still wish to know if anybody else has already implemented this.